# No gas for swap in matic

Tags: ether, polygon

How to swap WETH(POLYGON) or ETH(ETHERIUM) to MATIC with empty balance on polygon (no money for gas in matic). Current gas fee 30 usdt but i need only 0.01 MATIC.
Thank you

Comment: Please specify which platform or exchange you are using for the swap.